# How to assign char array in struct inline?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, inline, declare

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    const char *bytes;
    const char *desc;
};

SomeStruct example = { { 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13 }, "10-13" };
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: What error are you getting? If you are posting a question about *something not working* always post the error or incorrect behavior you are getting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably because `{ 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13 }` is an array of `char`, not a pointer to `char`.

Try `SomeStruct example = { "\x10\x11\x12\x13", "10-13" };` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `{ ... }` syntax is only suitable for assigning arrays, whereas `const char*` is a pointer, not an array.

If you declare `bytes` as an array instead – `char bytes[4];` – the assignment will work.

Comment: But is there any way to make something like that work? Like, I can declare an array like that (char blah[] = {0x1, 0x2,0x3};)

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler cannot convert `{1, 2, 3, 4}` to a pointer to bytes (it can convert "10-13" to a pointer to char).

You can specify the bytes in 'string' format (**if you don't mind an extra 0x00 in the memory pointed to by `bytes`**):

```
SomeStruct example = {"\x10\x11\x12\x13", "10-13"};
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your initializer sequence is valid for an
array, and the struct contains a pointer.  You can use
maraguida's response, using a string literal, but IMHO, this
isn't the most readable (and it won't work if, say, you decide
to replace the explicit constants with manifest constants).  The
more general solution is to define a separate, named array, and
use it:

```
char const structBytes10to13[] = { 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13 };
SomeStruct example = { structBytes10to13, "10-13" };
```

This will work for arbitrary initialization expressions in the
character array.